# Allocating a struct dirent without malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-alignment, readdir, strict-aliasing

I need to use `readdir_r()` to read the contents of a directory in a multithreaded program. Since the size of `struct dirent` is filesystem dependent, `man readdir_r` recommends

```
name_max = pathconf(dirpath, _PC_NAME_MAX);
if (name_max == -1)                     /* Limit not defined, or error */
    name_max = 255;                     /* Take a guess */
len = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + name_max + 1;
```

to find the size of the allocation needed. To allocate it

```
entryp = malloc(len);
```

is  called, and finally `readdir_r()` uses it like this:

```
struct dirent *returned;
readdir_r(DIR*, entryp, &returned);
```

However, I'd like to avoid calling `malloc()` (or any other manual memory management function).

One way I've thought of is

```
_Alignas(struct dirent) char direntbuf[len];
struct dirent *entryp = (struct dirent*) direntbuf;
```

This should give a correctly aligned allocation, but it violates strict aliasing. However, the buffer is never accessed via a `char*` so the most likely problem, the compiler reordering accesses to the buffer via different types, cannot occur.

Another way could be by `alloca()`, which returns a `void*`, avoiding strict aliasing problems. However, `alloca()` does not seem to guarantee alignment the way `malloc()` and friends do. To always get an aligned buffer, something like

```
void *alloc = alloca(len + _Alignof(struct dirent));
struct dirent *direntbuf = (struct dirent*)((uintptr_t)&((char*)alloc)[_Alignof(struct dirent)]&-_Alignof(struct dirent));
```

would be needed. In particular, the cast to `char *` is needed to perform arithmetic on a pointer, and the cast to `uintptr_t` is needed to do the binary `&`. This doesn't look more well-defined than allocating a `char[]`.

Is there a way to avoid manual memory management when allocating a `struct dirent`?

Comment: For <=C99: Calculate `len` as per your answer, then define `char buffer[len] `.

Comment: @alk: `char buffer[len]` is not necessarily correctly aligned for a `struct dirent`. Also, dereferencing an object of type `char` via a pointer of type `struct dirent` is undefined behaviour according to C.

Comment: Are you this "*but it violates strict aliasing*" holds for a `char`-array?

Comment: @alk. Well, C11 draft standard section 6.5 says that you can only access an object via a pointer to the type of that object or through a pointer to a character type. But if the object is already a `char`, that doesn't help here.

Comment: Ahok, this unfortunately does not hold the other way round ...:-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining this:

```
#include <stddef.h> /* For offsetof */
#include <dirent.h>


union U
{
  struct dirent de;
  char c[offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + NAME_MAX + 1]; /* NAME_MAX is POSIX. */
};
```

Comment: Wow, that is actually very clever... I'm impressed by this use of a union.

Comment: @jongware: How would a struct help here?

Comment: The same as what you propose but without needing an `offsetof` thingy.

Comment: Sry, but I do not get you? @Jongware

Comment: Just `struct U2 { struct dirent de; char c[NAME_MAX + 1]; /* NAME_MAX is POSIX. */ };`. I don't see why you thought of making it a *union* instead.

Comment: @Jongware: Ah! Nice thought :-), but how would you make sure the compiler would not add some padding between `de` and `c`?

Comment: @Jongware: If padding would be applied those bytes were used. Wouldn't this invoke UB?

Answer (score 0):

The readdir_r function signature is:

```
int readdir_r(DIR *dirp, struct dirent *entry, struct dirent **result);
```

And direct is a struct like this:

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
    off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
    unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
    unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                   by all file system types */
    char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
};
```

You have to pass a pointer to readdir_r but how you allocate memory for the dirent structure is entirely up to you.

You could do it like this and use a stack variable.

```
struct dirent entry = {0};
...
readdir_r(DIR*, &entry, &returned);
```

Comment: This is not protable, as only on Linux `d_name` is typed `char[256]`.